# Show that a function is continuous on a countably complete lattice

Tags: order-theory, fixed-point-theorems

I'm trying to show that if $D$ is a countably complete lattice and $F:D \rightarrow D$ is a monotone function, then the least fixed point is $\sup\{ f^n\bot \mid n \geq 0\}$, where $\bot$ is the least element of the lattice.

In order to show that I would like to use induction on $n$ and at some point I have to say that:

> $f(\sup\{f^n\bot \mid n \geq 0\}) = \sup\{f(f^n\bot) \mid n \geq 0\}$

that is true if $F$ if continuous. How can I demonstrate it?

Comment: How are you defining continuous?

Comment: If I'm not wrong @WilliamElliot a function _f_ is _continuous_ if it _monotone_ and for all non-empty chains hold that _sup{f d, d∈Y} = f(sup(Y))_. (I'm assuming that f is defined as in the question, so it is defined _f:D→D_ and D is a complete lattice)

Comment: What is Y??????

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten to write that Y is a generic non-empty chain. So the definition will became: 

a function _f_ is continuous if it _monotone_ and for all non-empty chains _Y_ in _D_ hold that _sup{f d, d∈Y} = f(sup(Y))_.

Comment: Continuity then directly answers the question as iteration by f creates a chain.

Comment: I have cannot understand. Can you explain me that more formally please?

Comment: Let n = bottom.  n,  fn,  ffn,  fffn,... is a chain.

Comment: But it must hold for all non-empty chains in _D_. Can I use for example the hypothesis that _D_ is countably or it is not important?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what may be the accurate description of the problem.

An (partial) order (S,<=) is countably complete when
for all countable A, sup A is in S.

A function f:S -> S, is continuous when for all nonempty chains C,
f(sup C) = sup f(C).

When S isn't complete but only countably complete, to makes sense
of the problem, let's define a countably continuous function
f:S -> S, as for all nonempty countable chains C, f(sup C) = sup f(C).

If S is countably complete, there's a bottom element b in S.
Proposition.  If S is countably complete and f:S -> S, is
increasing and countably continuous, then C = { f^n(b) | n = 0,1,.. }
is a notempty countable chain and a = sup C is a fixed point of f.

Proceeding b <= f(b), f(b) <= ff(b),... by induction, it's apparent
that C is a chain.  Thus f(sup C) = sup f(C).  Since f in increasing,
sup C <= sup f(C).  Since f(C) = { f^n(b) | n = 1,2,.. } is
a subset of C, sup f(C) <= sup f(C).  Whence f(sup C) = sup C, QED.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes. Thanks, now I get it:)

So the statement that I would like to show (if D is a countably complete lattice and F:D→D is a monotone function, then the least fixed point is sup{F^n⊥∣n≥0}, where ⊥ is the least element of the lattice) holds only if I assume F continuous and not in general, is that true?

Comment: A function which is countably complete is increasing.  The proof holds for increasing functions.  Decreasing functions are a 2nd and trivial case.  f is countable continuous.  Continuous requires a complete order.